# boost.test: compile errors when STL code is included within a test suite

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, c++-chrono, boost-test

My setup:

- windows 10
- `msys2` with

  - [`g++` 12.2.0](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc?repo=mingw64)
  - [`boost.test` 1.81.0](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-boost)

My test file:

```cpp
// test.cpp
#define BOOST_TEST_MAIN
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE a_nice_testing_attempt
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>  // this is available

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(MyNiceTestSuite)  // (*)

#include <chrono>
// actually I want to test much more, but I narrowed
// the problem down to this minimal snippet

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END() // (*)
```

Then I try to compile as:
`g++ test.cpp -o test.exe`

And get a bunch of errors (>1700 lines to be precise). Here's some at the very top:

```
In file included from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/chrono.h:37,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/chrono:39,
                 from test_main.cpp:17:
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/ratio:58:24: error: expected template-name before '<' token
   58 |     : integral_constant<intmax_t, (_Pn < 0) ? -1 : 1>
      |                        ^
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/ratio:58:24: error: expected '{' before '<' token
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/ratio:63:24: error: expected template-name before '<' token
   63 |     : integral_constant<intmax_t, _Pn * __static_sign<_Pn>::value>
      |                        ^
```

And some from the bottom:

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/chrono.h:1371:47:   required from 'static MyNiceTestSuite:
:std::chrono::time_point<MyNiceTestSuite::std::filesystem::__file_clock, _Dur> MyNiceTestSuite::std:
:filesystem::__file_clock::_S_from_sys(const MyNiceTestSuite::std::chrono::time_point<MyNiceTestSuit
e::std::chrono::_V2::system_clock, _Dur2>&) [with _Dur = MyNiceTestSuite::std::chrono::duration<long
 long int, MyNiceTestSuite::std::ratio<1, 1000000000> >]'
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/chrono.h:1338:27:   required from here
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/chrono.h:1020:16: error: cannot convert '__time_point' {ak
a 'MyNiceTestSuite::std::chrono::time_point<MyNiceTestSuite::std::filesystem::__file_clock, int>'} t
o 'int' in return
 1020 |         return __time_point(__lhs.time_since_epoch() -__rhs);
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                |
      |                __time_point {aka MyNiceTestSuite::std::chrono::time_point<MyNiceTestSuite::s
td::filesystem::__file_clock, int>}
```

If I remove the lines marked with the astherisk (i.e. `BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE` related), then it compiles without a problem. Unfortunately I am unable to progress from here and my question is rather vague:

- what is going on here and how could I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE` macro introduces a namespace. Standard library headers must not be included anywhere but in the global namespace.

This is a example not using any libs other than the standard library which should result in compiler errors similar to yours:

```
#define ADD_NAMESPACE 1

#if ADD_NAMESPACE
namespace Foo
{
#endif

#include <chrono>

#if ADD_NAMESPACE
}
#endif
```

[Godbolt Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:24,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:24,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:24,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:24,startLineNumber:1),source:%27%23define+ADD_NAMESPACE+1%0A%0A%23if+ADD_NAMESPACE%0Anamespace+Foo%0A%7B%0A%23endif%0A%0A%23include+%3Cchrono%3E%0A%0A%23if+ADD_NAMESPACE%0A%7D%0A%23endif%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:conformance,i:(compilers:!((compilerId:gsnapshot,options:%27%27),(compilerId:clang_trunk,options:%27%27),(compilerId:vcpp_v19_latest_x64,options:%27%27)),editorid:1,langId:c%2B%2B,libs:!()),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Conformance+Viewer+(Editor+%231)+3/15%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

(change to `#define ADD_NAMESPACE 0` to make the compilation work.)

Simply moving the include should work.

```
#include <chrono>

#define BOOST_TEST_MAIN
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE a_nice_testing_attempt
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>  // this is available

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(MyNiceTestSuite)  // (*)
// actually I want to test much more, but I narrowed
// the problem down to this minimal snippet

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END() // (*)
```

Comment: Awesome. I am failing to find the documentation for this. Is there some reference you could append to or link in your answer? Btw, edited the title to better match the problem on a generic level.

Comment: @deponovo The documentation only seems to mention that the macro "works **very similar to** a namespace" which isn't exactly stating this properly. The only option here seems to be to take a look at the defines related to the macro definition in the source code ( https://github.com/boostorg/test/blob/9286fb0c0fe3bd6ac9a6c496735efa30865e63ac/include/boost/test/unit_test_suite.hpp#L59 ) or alternatively use functionality of an IDE providing a preview of the macro expansion. (Or having the compiler run the preprocessor only, but that will result 10k-s LOC to look through.)